# clustering using t-distributed sne coordinates

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

Let's say you have data on cars: a matrix of 10,000 rows and 10 feature columns (mpg, engine size, horsepower...etc.) and you want to explore the high dimensional data. You could:

(1) Run kmeans or some other clustering algorithm on the dataset...picking the number of clusters 
(2) First reduce the dimensionality of the dataset with PCA and pass PC1 and PC2 to the clustering algorithm...picking the number of clusters

BUT can you also 
(3) First reduce the the dimensionality of the dataset with TSNE and pass the 2 TSNE coordinates to the clustering algorithm...picking the number of clusters

Does anyone do #3? After looking at the results of TSNE the 2D coordinates change each time TSNE is run. For example, a car might have both negative TSNE coordinates and then if the algorithm is run again it can have both positive TSNE coordinates. For example, if the coordinates are passed to a clustering algorithm a car might be in cluster 4 then on re-run it is in cluster 7 or 6 etc. TSNE seems like a great visualization tool and you'd want to be able to cluster off of it.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This great answer mostly answers your question:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/264647/7828

It gives a number of examples where **tSNE plots show clusters that don't exist in the input data**, I.e., that are very much **misleading**.

The one problem *not* discussed yet is getting tSNE to yield meaningful results on your data at all. tSNE uses squared Euclidean inside of the Gaussian. That means it is *very* sensitive to scale. As long as your input data has similar scales (it is mostly used on images, where each pixel does have the same scale) it works good. But on your cars data example, you will have the common scaling problems, and get results that are not very statistically meaningful. 1 mph is not the same as 1 wheel. tSNE can't solve this, on the contrary: tSNE is very sensitive to your preprocessing choices (and in fact, in the original tSNE paper, they used PCA as additional preprocessing step).

Comment: I scaled my inputs and did not use PCA

Comment: Did you call some "automatic" scaling, or actually spend time to make sure the local Gaussian assumption of tSNE is appropriate? It's not as if 0.1234 mph equal 0.25 wheels either. Just squeezing everything into 0:1 is a hack, not a solution.

Comment: they were all standardized z-scores. What is the typical way to confirm/reject gaussian assumption?

Comment: May work okayish, but there is no guarantee this is appropriate for the data. Don't underestimate the need to fine-tune preprocessing.

Comment: yes. can you advise how you'd know if the local gaussian assumption is appropriate?

Comment: I do not know the solution to this. I'd not try to solve this at the end, but earlier. Are the data distributions similar, and do they reflect the *desired* feature importance? I don't think math can answer this. If you have 100 useless variables, and 2 that matter, they will have very little effect and it will work horribly if you just standardize.